# Parse a string in C#

Tags: c#

I've the following string that I get from a method. I would like to parse it and make pairs. The order of input string will not change.

INPUT:

```
ku=value1,ku=value2,ku=value3,ku=value4,ku=value5,lu=value6,lu=value7,lu=value8,lu=value9
```

OUTPUT

```
Name    value1
Title   value2
School  value3
.
.
.
Age     value9
```

I think I can read through the string and assign `value` to the left hand side as I go and so on. However, I am very new to C#.

Comment: You can use string.split(',') to break it up into the individual parts then loop through those parts and use string.split('=') to get the key/value pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `string.Split` and split imput string to list key-value pair then split each pair to key and value. Tahts all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

void Main()
    {
        string str = "ku=value1,ku=value2,ku=value3,ku=value4,ku=value5,lu=value6,lu=value7,lu=value8,lu=value9";

```
    var tempStr = str.Split(',');
    var result = new List<KeyValue>();

    foreach(var val in tempStr)
    {
        var temp = val.Split('=');
        var kv = new KeyValue();
        kv.Name = temp[0];
        kv.Value = temp[1];

        result.Add(kv);
    }

}

public class KeyValue
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Value{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the first part you can do this using String split as follow

1. **Split String** on `,` using `String.Split` method creating sequence of string `{"ku=value1","ku=value2",...}`
2. Use Linq's `Select` method to **apply an additional transformation**
3. Use **Split again** on each item on the '=' character
4. Select the **item to the right** of the '=', at **index 1** of the newly split item
5. Loop through everything and print your results

Here's the code

```
var target = "ku=value1,ku=value2,ku=value3,ku=value4,ku=value5,lu=value6,lu=value7,lu=value8,lu=value9";

var split = target.Split(',').Select(a=>a.Split('=')[1]).ToArray();
var names = new[]{"Name","Title","School",...,"Age"};

for(int i=0;i<split.Length;i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(names[i]+"\t"+split[i]);
}
```

If you want to find out more about how to use these methods you can look at the MSDN documentation for them :

- [String.Split(char[]) Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Enumerable.Select Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to try this way. Split() plus regular expression

```
    string inputString = "ku=value1,ku=value2,ku=value3,ku=value4,ku=value5,lu=value6,lu=value7,lu=value8,lu=value9";

    string pattern = "(.*)=(.*)";

    foreach(var pair in inputString.Split(','))
    {

        var match = Regex.Match(pair,pattern); 
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} {1}",match.Groups[1].Value, match.Groups[2].Value));
    }
```

Comment: Regexes are overkill here; and if you were to use them, for efficiency you should instantiate a `Regex` instance once and use the non-static `Match()` member function instead of the static `Regex.Match()`. But the other answers involving `String.Split()` are superior.

Comment: I see. Thanks for comment